# Rearrange html table with CSS

Tags: html, css, html-table

I have a html table like this, but with several tbody elements like this.

```
<table>
 <tbody>
  <tr>
   <td>Header 1</td>
   <td>Header 2</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
   <td>Content 1</td>
   <td>Content 2</td>
  </tr>
 </tbody>
</table>
```

Is there someway I can change the look of this table with CSS to look like a table arranged this way:

```
<table>
 <tbody>
  <tr>
   <td>Header 1</td>
  <tr/>
  <tr>
   <td>Content 1</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
   <td>Header 2</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
   <td>Content 2</td>
  <tr/>
 </tbody>
</table>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One way you can do this is to use pseudo elements with a `data` attribute.

The `content` property of the pseudo element will call the `data` attribute, which will contain the same text as the header for that column.

Just hide the table header and display the pseudo elements using a media query (or in whatever other circumstance you want).

```css
table {
  width: 500px;
  border-collapse: collapse;
}
td {
  border: 1px solid gray;
}
@media all and (max-width: 600px) {
  tr:nth-child(1) {
    display: none;
  }
  tr {
    display: block;
    width: 100%;
  }
  tr td {
    display: block;
    width: 100%;
  }
  tr td::before {
    content: attr(data-header);
    display: block;
  }
}
```

```html
<table>
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td>Header 1</td>
      <td>Header 2</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td data-header="Header 1">Content 1</td>
      <td data-header="Header 2">Content 2</td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>

<p style="margin-left: 210px">&larr; resize &rarr;</p>
```

Comment: This does not change the layout of the table.

Comment: @MrZach You need to expand the snippet to full screen, then narrow your browser window enough to see the layout change kick in. Nothing happens until your screen gets narrower than 600 pixels.

Comment: Thank you, did not read your css good enough to catch the max-width. was just testing it :)

Answer (score 0):

You're able to apply other values to the `display` property on elements of that table, so you can easily change the layout. This is a common responsive design technique, where we'll usually display each table row in its own block before breaking out to t

Here's a CodePen using this technique to display the row with the Content cells to the right of the row with the Header cells: https://codepen.io/jrrdnx/pen/oeWmzL

Unfortunately with the way that table is structured, I don't think there's a way to alternate between one cell of the first row, one cell of the second row, then jump back to another cell of the first row, etc. If you know the length of the content of each cell you may be able to provide the appropriate table cells with the proper padding to stagger the content (as shown in the CodePen in `#table3`.

Comment: Thank you for your code, I also found some similar css to arrange it the way you did, but did not find any for the way I need it to be. Guess it might not be possible then.